# Wireshark: interfaces refresh with monitor mode unchecked when I check it

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

Whenever I turn on the monitor mode for my wlan interface from the *Capture interfaces* dialog box, I can see for a moment that the text in *Link layer header* changes from `Ethernet` to `802.11 plus radiotap header`, but less than a second after that, the interfaces are reloaded (i.e. the interface list got emptied and then repopulated), and the mentioned interface is spawned again with `Ethernet` header and monitor mode unchecked.

How can I keep the monitor mode on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour can be observed, when your wireless interface is not in monitor mode, but e.g. in managed mode.
To fix this, on a Linux machine do e.g. the following (replace `wlan0` with the name of your wireless interface):

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Now when you start wireshark you should be able to check the monitor mode box and `802.11 plus radiotap header` should stay on.